# reset webpage to its initial state

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis-js-api

I have written a clear function which is supposed to clear map and combo box. But I want to reset the webpage to its initial state. I have tried APP.restart()

```
App.restart = function() {
        var child,
        child_process = require("child_process"),
        gui = require('nw.gui'),
        win = gui.Window.get();
        if (process.platform == "darwin")  {
            child = child_process.spawn("open", ["-n", "-a", process.execPath.match(/^([^\0]+?\.app)\//)[1]], {detached:true});
       } else {
            child = child_process.spawn(process.execPath, [], {detached: true});
       }
        child.unref();
        win.hide();
        gui.App.quit();
}
```

But nothing works.
I do not need to reload function. Can anyone tell how to reset the webpage to its initial state?

Answer (score 0):

Follow any one of this:

```
1.Prevent page from caching (with response headers from server);
2.Clear all fields each time page is loaded with Javascript.
```

Example with jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('your_form_input_fields_id').val('');

    });
</script>
```

See this link: [reset webpage](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-clear-form-data-when-user-navigate-back-after-submit-in-html-form/117137)

Comment: it is not a form. it is webpage display map

Comment: You can see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157926/google-map-reset-to-initial-state